# Соединить три массива

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

Есть три массива, и из каждого нужно записать данные в одну и ту же таблицу в бд.

```
foreach($_POST['pole'] as $pole){
    $pole;
}

foreach($_POST['filtr'] as $filtr){
    $filtr;
}

foreach($_POST['default'] as $default){
    $default;
}
```

Пробовал в первом массиве записать `$pole`, а в остальных сделать UPDATE, 
пробовал записывать всё в разные таблицы, но там столкнулся с другими проблемами.

Comment: $arr = array($pole,$filtr,$default); или  
$arr = array($_POST['pole'],$_POST['filtr'],$_POST['default']);

Comment: А данные в каком виде хранятся? Просто array(1,2,3)? Или как-то array('first'=>'1', 'asd'=>'dsa')?

Число элементов массивов совпадает? Если есть ключ index из первого массива, то данные для обновления расположены под тем же ключом `index` в других массивах?

Т.е. вопрос вот в чем - как для первого массива я могу получить соответствующие данные из второго массива (ну и из третьего тоже)?

Возможно, достаточно будет просто:

    $result = array(); $pole = $_POST['pole']; $filtr = $_POST['filtr'];
    foreach ($pole as $key => value) {
        $result[] = array($pole[$key], $filtr[$key]);
    }

Comment: Спасибо, чутка переделал

Comment: "вопрос вот в чем" - это был мой вопрос к вам.

Если все массивы так же как и массив pole сделаны и элементы в них совпадают, значит, использовав мой способ, вы три массива объедините в один. А из него уже можно будет строить и SQL. У меня в комменте место заканчивалось, поэтому я только два массива объединял, вам надо добавить еще и третий.

Посмотрите [этот вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/387383). Там описан способ как из массива вставить данные одним запросом.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, чем array_merge не подходит http://ideone.com/tQtjmW

Comment: @barseon:

    $a = array(1, 2);
    $b = array(1, 2);
    $result = array_merge($a, $b); // [1, 2, 1, 2]

и как вы теперь будете определять, что первая 1 - это одно поле, а второе 1 - это второе поле той же записи?

Не проще ли сделать так:

    $result = array();
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = array($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    }
    $result // [ [1, 1], [2, 2] ]

В этом случае для каждой записи можно сказать какие у нее будут значения.

Правда, можно было и без такого мерджа, с двумя массивами работать, но так будет нагляднее, а значит и багов будет меньше.

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите, пожалуйста, вывод:

    <?php
        var_dump($_POST['pole']);
        var_dump($_POST['filtr']);
        var_dump($_POST['default']);
    ?>

Также интересует хотя-бы примерный формат таблицы в БД, куда заносить данные